# How do I switch between my POV and a character's POV midway a story?

Tags: character-development, pov

I was recently writing a scene in my story, and wanted to switch between POVs of me and a character Carlie to develop her character, making her more connected to the reader; I began it this way:

> "Hey, you! Yes, yes, you! Carlie here. No, I’m not talking to any character, I’m talking to you, the reader. I’m going to continue from where the author left off."

The whole scene in her POV was written in quotes, but the opening transition (the line above) does not look formal to me in any way, and I can't find any examples to help myself, everywhere it's just complete chapters written in one POV. I need a formal example, or a sentence from a literary fiction to get rid of the confusion on how to switch POVs, with or without breaking the flow of the story, the latter more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keep Your Readers Inside Your Story

A very important rule to keep in mind: 
**You don't want to pull you reader out of your story.**
Your readers being pulled out of your story will be a jarring experience for them (I mean, hopefully they were totally immersed in the story until now and they're not rudely being awaken). They will start noticing plot holes, inconsistencies, and, other things that annoy them about your book. Too much of this and they'll start looking for a book that holds their interest better.
 The best way for your reader to finish your story is if the reading is so natural that they're not aware that they're doing it. So, no jarring them out of the book.

This could include sentences such as

> I’m going to continue from where the author left off

I mean, they'll suddenly go "huh, I forgot! I'm reading a book. None of this is actually real."  Which you don't want.

### How Do You Change POV?

So, now we get to the second question. **How can you change POV in a way that flows with the story?**
There are endless ways. The change should be subtle. And clear that we are now seeing things from a different character's eyes. 
I think the best way to do this is by starting with your new character in the beginning of something. Whether it's a new chapter, a new section, it should be *something* new.

You may even be able to just start writing from Carlie's POV in the beginning of the chapter/section etc. and it will be clear enough that we've changed characters. (This is most likely if you're switching from first to third POV, or if both are in third person). I'm not familiar enough with your story to say if this is possible. However, as long as she has a different sounding POV than the first POV, it could work.
Or you can try spelling it out for your reader. Write Carlie's name at the top of the chapter. Start the section with a message to your readers, such as *Carlie's Story:* or *Carlie's POV*. Or even give Carlie a paragraph to introduce herself. 
*Hey, I'm Carlie. 15 years old. With the cutest little brother in the world and a pet cat. My world turned upside down the day that...*

I'm not sure I completely answered your question. Feel free to add more details or make it clearer, if you'd like. 
In the meantime, [here are 12 examples of books with a few POV](https://rivetedlit.com/2019/03/26/12-books-with-multiple-perspectives/)
Also, [this article on 8 tips for writing pov](https://www.nownovel.com/blog/points-of-view-8-tips/) is one I believe you'll find helpful.